# How can I change webkit css with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

This doesn't change it. I don't know why

```
$("#description").animate({"-webkit-line-clamp":8},500);
console.log($("#description").css("-webkit-line-clamp"))//returns 3
```

I have also tried

```
 $("#description").animate({"-webkit-line-clamp":"8"},500);
```

Comment: at least `$("#description").css({"-webkit-line-clamp":"8"});` works. But it's probably a non-animating property, that's why?

Comment: are you getting any error , warning in console

Answer (score 3):

Here an example how you could animate it:

```js
$("#description").animate({
    webkitLineClamp: 8
}, {
    duration: 5000,
    step: function (v) {
        $(this).css({webkitLineClamp: parseInt(v,10).toString()});
    }
})
```

```css
 body {
    padding: 20px;
    font: 1.2em/1.2em'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
.module {
    width: 250px;
    margin: 0 0 1em 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.module p {
    margin: 0;
}
.line-clamp {
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-line-clamp: 3;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Line Clampin'</h1>




<div id="description" class="module line-clamp">
    <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I just used simple
    $("#description").animate({
        webkitLineClamp: 8
    })

Answer (score 2):

[This page](http://css-tricks.com/line-clampin/) seems to suggest you need display: -webkit-box;

```
$("#description").css({"display":"-webkit-box"}).animate({"-webkit-line-clamp":8},500);
```

It also offers up a few alternatives - [Clamp.js](https://github.com/josephschmitt/Clamp.js/) may offer you a more 'unversal' solution albeit pure JS implementation - but you seem to be going down that route anyway.